# netbeans plugin installation failed, org.netbeans.modules.maven.model requirement

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, plugins

I'm trying to install a plugin on netbeans but I'm having a hell of time installing it. 
I'm having this problem : [image: screenshot]

although I can't find the org.netbeans.modules.maven.model plugin anywhere. I'm not every experienced with netbeans, thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

that error means that a dependency is missing, it's one of the maven modules. Make sure you install maven support and have it enabled.

this particular module doesn't expose public api, so whoever is using it must depend on implementation version. So in this case it's possible that the license changer plugin assumes different version of netbeans than you have. No solution for that apart from checking if there's different version of the license checker plugin that depends on netbeans 8.1

Comment: i checked, I do have the correct version of the plugin (license changer for netbeans 8.1), It is still not working with no progress. I'm completly lost, what should I do (how do I install maven on netbeans (I already have it on my computer) ? How do I enable it, I can't find anything about that on google, I'm using ubuntu btw)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found where the problem was : Ubuntu's netbeans installation from apt-get doesn't install any modules, and modules such as Maven junit cannot be found on the internet.

To activate them and let netbeans download them the same way the android SDK would do you have to go to **"tool > plugin > setting" and activate the three boxes "certified plugins" + "Netbeans distribution" + "plugin portal". wait for sec and restart netbeans, it should then prompt you with a dialog asking you to accept the installation** of a lot of plugin (which are part of the everyday life of a 'normal' netbeans user), in them was the one I needed (maven Junit). I could then after further restart install the plugin I wanted in the first place (license changer).

I think it should be notified to new netbeans users on ubuntu that they are using, unlike everyone else, a module free version of netbeans and they need to be activated and downloaded by the software afterward.

finally I would like to apologize for my silly english as it is not my mother tongue, thank you for your help and understanding